# How to find a column having multiple common values in a single dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data Frame

```
1          2          3         4      
apple      juice      fruit     edible
banana     smoothie   fruit     edible
orange     juice      fruit     edible
berries    jelly      fruit     edible
```

Output I want

```
DataFrame 1:

3
fruit
fruit
fruit
fruit

DataFrame 2:

4
edible
edible
edible
edible
```

Also it should print 'Column 3, 4 have common values'

Any Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) for filter by only unique columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.nunique().eq(1)]
print (df)
       3       4
0  fruit  edible
1  fruit  edible
2  fruit  edible
3  fruit  edible
```

And then for list of `one list DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
L = [df1[x].to_frame() for x in df1.columns]
print (L)
[       3
0  fruit
1  fruit
2  fruit
3  fruit,         4
0  edible
1  edible
2  edible
3  edible]

print (L[0])
       3
0  fruit
1  fruit
2  fruit
3  fruit

print (L[1])
        4
0  edible
1  edible
2  edible
3  edible
```

And for dynamic pring is used `join` with `f-string`s:

```
print (f'Column {", ".join(df1.columns.astype(str))} have common values')
Column 3, 4 have common values
```